# Include content based on url with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to include content based on url with javascript. For example, if the url is:

```
http://foo.com/test
```

then include the following content from somefile.html. Can this be done in javascript? If so, how? I don't want to use an iframe.

Comment: Which following content? What do you want to do? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I would like to include a file using an if statement based on what the url is. Sort of like in php. Can something like this be done in javascript?

Comment: Do you want to show the whole file instead of the original file that would be located at that URL or just embed it into the page? Where is the URL coming from? If you want to do what I mentioned first then you are using the wrong tools for solving the problem...

Comment: I'm a jerk, I know, but these incomplete questions are always from people with low rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is really the better tool to use for this. However, if you cannot use PHP or another server-side scripting language such as Perl, Python, VBScript, or C#, you could use the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method of the [jQuery JavaScript Library](http://jquery.com/) combined with code to check the URL using [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location), for example:

```
$(function() {
    if(window.location.pathname == '/test') {
        $('#idOfContainer').load('/somefile.html');
    }
});
```

For more complex cases, you could [use regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bump an old thread but I've just been working on this - Pleasestand's answer didn't work for me so I made a few adjustments and now it works perfectly.

```
$(function() {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf('/yourURL/')!==-1) {
        $('#containerdiv').load('/your.php');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, JavaScript gets run on the client, so you can't exactly decide to show a different page.  If you want to do serverside redirects, you will have to write some serverside code or configure your web server to redirect.

However, if you are on the page, you can figure out what page you are on, and execute some clientside code.

You can get the current location like this:

```
window.location.href
```

So you can write something like:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('http://foo.com/test') >= 0) {
    window.location.href = 'http://foo.com/somefile.html';
} // <-- redirect to http://foo.com/somefile.html
```

Or you can write an iframe into the page pointed at your 'somefile.html'.

Answer (score 0):

You can include content using AJAX http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest. You can check the URL with the location object https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location